# I want to use Code First Migration but wrong message

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 migrations. First is AddEmployee and Second is AddCustomer.

**I want to run :**

```
 Update-Database –TargetMigration: AddEmployee
```

**But is shows :**

> More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly
>   'Konstructor'. Specify the name of the one to use.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have two Contexts in your project. You need to specify the name like so:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: AddEmployee -ConfigurationTypeName MyContextConfiguration
```